# How to use passport js with mongo db atlas?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js

I have an  database deployed on mongodb atlas and i want to use passport in my cloud web app which is in written in node js ? should i use passport local or passport http and also how should i connect them in order to authenticate login using passport js ?